# How to change URL not not trigger $route changes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a situation where I want the URL in the address bar to change, but I don't want Angular to refresh the controller or view like in a normal route change.

So, going to `/data` then clicking on a link saying `/data/just-blue` would only refresh a part of the `ngView` not the entire view.

How is that possible?

Currently I have those 2 paths defined as separate `.when()` paths in the app `.config()` method.

Thanks.

Comment: If you can use querystring you can achieve it with /data?color=just-blue.

Comment: Sure, that's a way. I was even thinking of has fragments. But would it be possible with pushState so I have /data/just-blue?

Comment: `ngView` is updated every time the route changes, you can't just update a portion of what is in `ngView` unless you get the backend very involved, this is a problem because you can only have one `ngView`.  What you want to do is have a look at `ui-router` https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router which introduces the `ui-view` directive and allows for more views such that you can update portions of a page upon route/state changes rather than having the main view loaded fully.

Comment: I understand that. What I wanted to do is to prevent route change when switching from `/data` to `/data/just-blue` and let the controllers deal with changing only part of the view, which in my particular case just means fetching a different dataset and nothing more. Just assigning that new data to the scope will populate the list which has an ng-repeat on it. So there's absolutely no point in changing route in this example.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you can do the following:

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        console.log(event, next, current);
        console.log(next);
        if (next == 'http://localhost:9000/data/just-blue') {
            setTimeout(function() {
                 $window.history.pushState("object or string", 
                 "Title", '/data/just-blue)'},20);
            event.preventDefault();
            // ... update your view
        }
    });
```

Mind that I used `setTimeout` instead of `$timeout`.

Comment: Hm, interesting solution. Kind of hacky though, they should have thought of a smarter way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution: http://joelsaupe.com/programming/angularjs-change-path-without-reloading/ (not using pushState)